# Click "Login with Facebook" div by other link button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

"Login with Facebook" funtionality is working fine for me but my requirement is to click that button from the other anchor link and hide the actual button.

I am not getting which control id should I take to click "Login with Facebook" div from javascript or jquery.

```
<head>
<title>Facebook Login Authentication</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d) {
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));

// Init the SDK upon load
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId: '6082xxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
status: true, // check login status
cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
});
    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture";
        // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
        FB.api('/me', { locale: 'tr_TR', fields: 'name, email' },
           function (response) {


               document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = response.name;
               document.getElementById('Email').innerHTML = response.email;
               document.getElementById('profileImg').src = uid;
           }
         );


        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
$("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () { FB.logout(function () { window.location.reload(); }); });
}
function ClickFacebookLogin() {

    //$('#auth-loggedout').trigger('click');
    var myEl = document.getElementById('FBdiv'); 
    myEl.click();
}



</script>
<h1>
Facebook Login Authentication Example</h1>
<div id="auth-status">
<div id="auth-loggedout">

<div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" scope="email" id="FBdiv">Login with Facebook</div>
</div>
<a onclick="ClickFacebookLogin();">Click FB</a>

<div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>(<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a><br />
Email: <b><span id="Email"></span></b><br />
Profile Image: <img id="profileImg" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This sounds suspicious, what are you exactly trying to do? Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for information on how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Simply don’t use the Login Button plugin, but call FB.login …

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing:

`<a onclick="ClickFacebookLogin();">Click FB</a>`

to this:

`<a onclick="ClickFacebookLogin">Click FB</a>`

ie. Remove the (); otherwise you are executing the function right away rather than waiting for the onclick event to trigger it.